# Jquery not working inside UserControl

Tags: c#, jquery, user-controls

i'm facing a problem tryin to execute a simples jquery inside my userControl. This jquery doesn't has anything with the pages that is goin to load my UC.

the code looks like it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(s, e) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            tooltip();
        });
    }
</script>
```

i tryied to debug using firebug but not even the breakpoint is reach.. by some reason i think that the browser is just ignoring my script.

it's my first ask here.. sry anything.

Comment: do not forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write just below lines because ready function get fire automatically when page get loaded with all controls

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            tooltip();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: and the real problem come.. by some reason my tooltip style is gettin lost on pageload.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            tooltip();
        });

</script>
```